# Why did Raymond Williams always take the best ones?

Tags: song-lyrics, interpretation, karate

In "Sever" from the Karate album  [*Unsolved*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsolved_(album)) (2000), we can hear the following lines:

> Because in my life there was only asbestos
>   And Raymond Williams, you always took the best ones
>   Now, like failed pedestrian dreams
>   That's how it seems to me

[Raymond Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Williams) 
(1921 – 1988) was a Welsh Marxist theorist who is well-known in literary theory for his book [*Marxism and Literature*](https://archive.org/details/marxismliteratur00will_0) (1977) and his influence on [cultural materialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_materialism_(cultural_studies)). However, why would the song say that he "always took the best ones"?

Comment: Could it be a reference to music producer Ray Williams? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Williams_(producer)

Comment: @Gaurav I don't know. I don't see a direct connection between Ray Williams and Karate. Also, why call him "Raymond Williams"?